# Importing Open Data set giving attribute error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, google-colaboratory

I am trying to import kaggle datasets using **opendatasets** module but after using pandas 1.1.2 with python 3.6v it is not working.
It's giving me this error during the import:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/opendatasets/utils/network.py in <module>()
      7 try:
----> 8     urlopen = urllib.request.urlopen
      9 except Exception:

AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'request'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last
```

PS. I'm working on virtual colab files and not on a local machine

Following is the command of what i am doing

```
import opendatasets as od

dataset_url='https://www.kaggle.com/rohanrao/air-quality-data-in-india'
od.download('https://www.kaggle.com/rohanrao/air-quality-data-in-india')
data_dir = './air-quality-data-in-india'
```

Comment: https://github.com/JovianML/opendatasets/issues/2

This package currently has some issues, it will be repaired soon

Comment: Yes that doesnt matter as the package is going through issues

Comment: @Divyessh is there a workaround ?

Comment: If it does not work then kindly undo the changes you made

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222579/private 
Join here

Comment: I will keep it open for around 10 mins

Comment: okay I will try to overcome your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
!pip install jovian opendatasets --upgrade --quiet
!pip install -q kaggle 
import urllib.request
import opendatasets as od
```

and then entering your kaggle username as well as your [kaggle key](https://www.kaggle.com/docs/api) allows you to import the dataset (until and unless it's not opendata set)